# Loading content to div from drop down

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm needing to load a page into a div with one variable being passed through the URL like **page.php?quantity=1**. This being done after the user selects something from the form's drop down menu. What would be a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

you could make use of [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/), as:

```
$( document ).on('change', '#yourDropdownId', function() {
   var val = $(this).val(), //get selected value
       url = 'page.php?quantity=' + val; 
   //load the page on div
   $( '#yourContentDivId' ).load( url );
});
```